# How to get GMT and their location's

Tags: android, timezone

I'm working on world clock and I need to get an array with the available gmts and another array with location can some one show me how do I do that?

Comment: "available gmts" makes no sense. There is only one GMT.  See [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time).

Answer (score 0):

`Locale.getAvailableLocales()` returns an array with available Locales. Then you can use Locale's methods like `getDisplayCountry()`or `getDisplayName()`. For references see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html